# estaria correcto mi codigo ya que tengo que usar mvc , jpa, jsp? entre otros

Tags: java, mysql, mvc, jpa

```
private boolean cargaDatos(Estudiante est, HttpServletRequest request) {
 boolean ok = true;
    String idi = request.getParameter("txtId");
    String apell = request.getParameter("txtApellido");
    String nom = request.getParameter("txtNombre");
    String recibida = request.getParameter("txtFechaIn");
    
   
    SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date fecha = new Date();
    try {
        fecha = formato.parse(recibida);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    est.setId(0);
    est.setApellidos(apell);
    est.setNombres(nom);
    est.setFechaingreso(fecha);
    
    try {
        est.setId(Integer.parseInt(idi));
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        ok = false;
    }
    
    
    return ok;}
```

Necesito un poco de ayuda ya que es bastante que tengo que realizar, no se si estaria bien el try catch porque tengo 2, ya que al momento de ejecutar, presentara algun error en comun. Se agradece la ayuda.

Comment: qué se supone que hace tu código? dónde te da un error? qué te preocupa? no se entiende la pregunta

Comment: estoy usando mysql, donde viene un dato de tipo date, y al llevar a java realize un try catch para contenerlo y otro try catch para el tipo entero donde idi en mysql es "id" de tipo int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las excepciones pueden ir dentro del mismo try, aunque en el momento que entre en una excepción, la otra no se ejecutará, o sea, si te dieran error las dos excepciones, solo te informaría de la primera que encontrara en el código, y te daría la segunda cuando hayas depurado la primera

Estando dentro del mismo try, las excepciones tienen que tener distinto nombre

```
private boolean cargaDatos(Estudiante est, HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean ok = true;
    String idi = request.getParameter("txtId");
    String apell = request.getParameter("txtApellido");
    String nom = request.getParameter("txtNombre");
    String recibida = request.getParameter("txtFechaIn");
  
    SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date fecha = new Date();
    
    est.setId(0);
    est.setApellidos(apell);
    est.setNombres(nom);
    est.setFechaingreso(fecha);
    
    try {
        fecha = formato.parse(recibida);
        est.setId(Integer.parseInt(idi));
    } catch (ParseException exP) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    } catch (NumberFormatException exF) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        ok = false;
    } finally {
        System.out.println("fin de programa");
    }
    return ok;
}
```

No se si es la respuesta que buscabas o tu duda va por otro lado

Comment: gracias amigo, por la ayuda:) se agradece